# Как убрать эту полоску между div-ами?

Tags: html, css, html5

Не могу понять, почему между двумя div появилась разделение. Подскажите как убрать. (Разделение между att и change)

```css
#body{
    height: 3300px;
}
.modal-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(226, 223, 222);
}
.modal-content{
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 35%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(68, 115, 177);
}
.att{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(196, 194, 106);
}
.change{
    height: 80%;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.change-text{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
.choise-but{
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(165, 144, 144);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.but-f{
    background-color: rgb(89, 184, 12);
}
.but-s{
    background-color:red;
}
.choise-but:hover{
    transform: scale(1.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="att">
    Вы хотите продолжить?
   </div>
   <div class="change">
    <span class="change-text">Если вы хотите продолжить нажмите кнопку "Да", если же хотите выйти, нажмите "Нет"</span>
    <div class="choise">
     <button value = "yes" class="choise-but but-f">Да</button>
     <button value = "no" class="choise-but but-s">Нет</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `att` активен бордер

`border-bottom: 1px solid;`